# Pause and resume a looping Task without using TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a simple program that inputs a number and starts counting from 0, I have 1 counter to do pause and resume (_nCurrentCount), the below code works fine, but I canceled Task on pause right?. Is there a way to just "pause" that Task without canceling it?

```
 private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnCancel.Enabled = true;
        

        //Pause
        if (tokenSource != null)
        {
            btnStart.Text = "RESUME";
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            tokenSource.Dispose();
            tokenSource = null;
        }
        //Start and resume
        else
        {
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            btnStart.Text = "PAUSE";

            countNumber(_nCurrentCount, tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                var _bPaused = false;

                if (!Disposing && !IsDisposed && tokenSource != null)
                    tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                    {
                        txtCount.Text = _nCurrentCount.ToString();
                        btnStart.Enabled = false;
                    }));
                }

                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                }
                else if (t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    _bPaused = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _bPaused = false;
                    _nCurrentCount = -1;
                    tokenSource.Dispose();
                    tokenSource = null;
                    btnStart.Text = "START";
                }

            }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
        }
    }
```

This is the countNumber Task:

```
private async Task countNumber(int pnStart, CancellationToken pCancellationToken)
    {
        if (pnStart < 0)
            pnStart = 0;
        for (int i = pnStart; i <= Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text); i++)
        {
            pCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            pnStart = i;
            _nCurrentCount = i;
            txtCount.Text = _nCurrentCount.ToString();
            
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a simple program. You've made this overly complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using `async`:

```
private int _target = 0;
private int _counter = 0;
private CancellationTokenSource cts = null;

private async Task Execute(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (true)
    {
        txtCount.Text = $"{++_counter}";
        if (_counter == _target)
        {
            btnStart.Text = "START";
            break;
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500.0));
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_target == _counter)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out int target) && target > 0)
        {
            _target = target;
            _counter = 0;
            txtCount.Text = $"{_counter}";
            btnStart.Text = "PAUSE";
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            await Execute(cts.Token);
        }
        else
        {
            txtCount.Text = "INVALID";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            cts = null;
            btnStart.Text = "RESUME";
        }
        else
        {
            btnStart.Text = "PAUSE";
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            await Execute(cts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private int _target = 0;
private int _counter = 0;

private async Task Execute()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (btnStart.Text == "PAUSE")
        {
            txtCount.Text = $"{++_counter}";
            if (_counter == _target)
            {
                btnStart.Text = "START";
                break;
            }
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500.0));
    }
}

private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnStart.Text == "START")
    {
        if (int.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out int target) && target > 0)
        {
            _target = target;
            _counter = 0;
            txtCount.Text = $"{_counter}";
            btnStart.Text = "PAUSE";
            await Execute();
        }
        else
        {
            txtCount.Text = "INVALID";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        btnStart.Text = btnStart.Text == "RESUME" ? "PAUSE" : "RESUME";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I am forced to do this with Task to "get a deeper understanding" of asynchronous programming.

Comment: @QuangGiap - I've given you an async approach.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your enthusiasm @enigmativity, but you still cancel Task when Pause right, luckily I found a way to Pause without canceling Task, that is using Task.Delay(-1) and cancel Task.Delay(-1) when I want to resume the counter Task

Comment: @QuangGiap - I added a non-canceling version - please keep in mind that this does now have a race condition and it isn't the best code. You should always use the cancelling method to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you, I know this is not the best way but I need to do it to practice and understand better asynchronous programming